# Finding the minimum unfilled index in grid

Tags: math, lua, grid, scalability, minimum

**For sake of this question I will refer to all grid indices, vertexes, or others as points.**
**So (1, 1) is a point on the grid, as an example.**

I am looking to find the least largest total-sized index in a grid. In this case (1, 1) would total out to 2, (2, 1) would total out to be 3 and the same goes for (1, 2).

**Expected Results**:

```
{ X = 1, Y = 1 }
{ X = 2, Y = 1 }
{ X = 1, Y = 2 }
{ X = 2, Y = 2 }
{ X = 3, Y = 1 }
{ X = 3, Y = 2 }
{ X = 1, Y = 3 }
{ X = 2, Y = 3 }
{ X = 3, Y = 3 }
```

**Actual Results**:

```
{ X = 1, Y = 1 }
{ X = 2, Y = 1 }
{ X = 1, Y = 2 }
{ X = 2, Y = 2 }
{ X = 3, Y = 2 }
{ X = 2, Y = 3 }
{ X = 3, Y = 3 }
{ X = 4, Y = 3 }
{ X = 3, Y = 4 }
```

**Code**:

```
local chunks = {}
local previous = {
    X = 0,
    Y = 0
}

local largest = {
    X = 0,
    Y = 0
}

local function addScene()
    local new = {
        X = (previous.X > previous.Y and previous.Y) or previous.X + 1,
        Y = (previous.X > previous.Y and previous.X) or previous.Y
    }
    
    if new.X == 0 then
        new.X = 1
    end
    
    if new.Y == 0 then
        new.Y = 1
    end
    
    largest.X = math.max(largest.X, new.X)
    largest.Y = math.max(largest.Y, new.Y)
    
    previous.X = new.X
    previous.Y = new.Y
    
    table.insert(chunks, new)
    return new
end

for i = 1, 3*3, 1 do
    local scene = addScene()
    print(i, "(" .. tostring(scene.X) .. ", " .. tostring(scene.Y) .. ")" .. "\n")
end
```

[Test For Yourself](http://tpcg.io/_QUDGJ7)

This code, as shown above, gets pretty close to what I'd like it to do but only up to a point and this must be scalable across larger, and larger, grids.

Comment: What's the meaning of total-sized index?

Comment: @shingo according to his explanation it's the sum of the coordinates. I cannot make any sense of "least largest" though.  what on earth is that supposed to mean? what problem are you actually trying to solve? if you want to build a grid, just build it. what's the purpose of that previous, largest nonsense? provide more context

Comment: @Piglet So I should reword that sentence. I meant lowest sized index, and by looking at my expected results you can sort of see that in acrion. Let's say (1, 1) and (1, 2) are filled. The next step, with the lowest total, would be (2, 1) because the total for it is 3, where if we went with (1, 3) or (3, 1) or even (2, 2) it would total 4. Anything else I can help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, most likely, inefficient this does end up giving close to desired result. You could simply reorganize the table to get it exactly like I showed in the question anyways.

```
local MAX_SIZE = {
    X = 3,
    Y = 3
}

local chunks = {}
local previous = {
    X = 0,
    Y = 0
}

local function addScene()
    local least = MAX_SIZE.X + MAX_SIZE.Y
    local new = {
        X = 0,
        Y = 0
    }
    
    for x = MAX_SIZE.X, 1, -1 do
        for y = MAX_SIZE.Y, 1, -1 do
            if chunks[tostring(x) .. '-' .. tostring(y)] then
                break
            end
            
            if x ~= 0 and y ~= 0 and x + y <= least then
                least = x + y
                new.X = x
                new.Y = y
            end
        end
    end
    
    if new.X == 0 then
        new.X = 1
    end
    
    if new.Y == 0 then
        new.Y = 1
    end
    
    previous.X = new.X
    previous.Y = new.Y
    chunks[tostring(new.X) .. '-' .. tostring(new.Y)] = new
    return new
end

for i = 1, 3*3, 1 do
    local scene = addScene()
    print(i, "(" .. tostring(scene.X) .. ", " .. tostring(scene.Y) .. ")" .. "\n")
end
```

[Try it out](http://tpcg.io/_OOIDZS)

**Results**:

```
1 (1, 1)
2 (1, 2)
3 (2, 1)
4 (1, 3)
5 (2, 2)
6 (3, 1)
7 (2, 3)
8 (3, 2)
9 (3, 3)
```